# Browser does not get defined css selector

Tags: html, css

I have following markup:

```
<div class="won-container">
   <div class="circle B"></div>
   <div class="circle B"></div>
   <div class="circle B"></div>
   <div class="circle B"></div>
   <div class="circle B"></div>
   <div class="circle R"></div>
</div>
```

and have defined following classes in external css stylesheet:

```
.won-container {
    float: left;
}

.circle {
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -12px;
}

.won-container .B
{
    background-image: url('../images/circle_blue.png') ;
}​
.won-container .G
{
    background-image: url('../images/circle_green.png');
}​
.won-container .R
{
    background-image: url('../images/circle_red.png');
}​
```

and it turns out that browser only get `.won-container .B` class showing blue image. Browser is not aware of `.won-container .R` selector. Any idea why?

Comment: *It does not even registered* means what?

Comment: It means that browser is showing images inside divs with class circle B. circle R - red image is not being shown

Comment: The code looks fine, is the image available? What browser are you using?

Comment: can you open the source code of your webpage in the browser ? Try to see if it can find the red image. (just search for "circle R" and click then on the link.)

Comment: works fine for me - http://jsfiddle.net/4kRyE/1/ perhaps it's you `margin-top:-12px` that is breaking things

Comment: Red image is availiable, opened it in browser; Firebug does not show  .won-container .R class selector when page is loaded but it is showing .won-container .B

Comment: Annndddd here: http://jsfiddle.net/Ljt59/1/ update the fiddle and show us your problem?

Comment: Hmmm... relative paths in url('../images/circle_red.png') ?

Comment: I have found, somehow Visual Studio inserted (e2 80 8b) non-printable character after .won-container .B bracket. :) Thank you all.